# How to create a scipt that will pull urls from one file and put it into another?

Tags: regex, url, logging, grep

I've been searching and I can't seem to find even just a simple grep code to do what I want. I want to take a url such as r2---sn-vgqs7nes.googlevideo.com, but not r3---sn-2xouxaxq5u5-5cxs.googlevideo.com and put them into a seperate file. Everything between r2---sn- and .googlevideo.com changes. A few examples of the varients:

- r2---sn-vgqs7nes.googlevideo.com

  - r4---sn-ab5l6n67.googlevideo.com
  - r4---sn-5hnednes.googlevideo.com
  - r12---sn-ab5l6nsz.googlevideo.com
  - r6---sn-a5mlrn7d.googlevideo.com
  - r3---sn-vgqsrn76.googlevideo.com
  - r6---sn-p5qlsne7.googlevideo.com
  - r2---sn-qxo7snel.googlevideo.com
  - r4---sn-q4f7sn7z.googlevideo.com
  - r1---sn-o097znez.googlevideo.com
  - r6---sn-q4f7sn7e.googlevideo.com

The characters between sn-(randomizes).googlevideo.com
Also, r(number) goes up to r20. Basically, I want to extract them from a log file which constanty updates and input into one that doesn't so, I can later use them. From lets say /opt/var/log/messages to /opt/var/log/list. Another thing I'd like to also do is check to make sure the url doesn't already exist before it inputs it.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have tried this. grep -oP '[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}\.googlevideo.com$' file >/opt/var/log/list . Got that from another post on here, but I don't think it would cover exactly all the varients of the urls. Had to remove the perl option because its not supported on tomato. So, grep -o '[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}\.googlevideo.com$' file >/opt/var/log/list It inputted nothing. Maybe I'm missing the file its suppose to check. Thats only half of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Stinsen Could you please post your desired output? Do you just want all lines starting with r2, or every line but not starting with r3?

Answer (score -1):

@john-goofy The urls go from r1 to r20 for each variant. The urls such as these r3---sn-(2xouxaxq5u5-5cxs).googlevideo.com don't need to be collected. These variants of urls in parentheses is important not to be collected because blocking those blocks the videos entirely. Those also go from r1-r20, but the part in parentheses doesn't change besides this part in parentheses, but only one letter sn-2xouxaxq5u5-(5cxs).googlevideo.com. Which  So, my desired output would be this:

Not collected: 
- (r1-20) ---sn-2xouxaxq5u5-5cxs.googlevideo.com
- (r1-20) ---sn-2xouxaxq5u5-5cxe.googlevideo.com
- (r1-20) ---sn-2xouxaxq5u5-5cx?.googlevideo.com
- The third one I forget the letter.
- manifest.googlevideo.com

Collected: 
Everything else such as the ones in my OP. I already have a few thousand collected, but it takes way too long manually doing each one.

(Blocking all these gets rid of youtube ads for the most part. There's some I think included in the above urls, but blocking them blocks everything.)

And it would all be inputted from /opt/var/log/messages to /opt/var/log/list

Comment: Please edit your question rather than adding additional information as an answer.